# XAMARIN - List View com Binding sem Informação

Tags: c#, xamarin, listview, binding

Estou fazendo um projeto com Xamarin.Forms e estou com um problema.
O projeto é referente a rota de ônibus da minha cidade, porém ao fazer o código e jogar para a tela, por mais que tenha o BINDING o mesmo não chega a ir para a tela, assim deixando a tela vazia.

O problema, em questão, seria que estou fazendo binding, seguindo tutorial do que realmente preciso (link do que estou me baseando para fazer: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping/), mas por mais que eu faça parecido com isso, adaptando ao que preciso, minha listview fica em branca por mais que tenha informações no **Items**

Alguma sugestão do que pode ser para o binding não estar funcionando neste caso em especifico?

Desde já, agradeço.

**List View:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="APPDiretoPonto.View.CalendarioOnibus"
             Title="Horários">
    <!--IsGroupingEnabled="True"  -->
    <ListView x:Name="MyListView"

            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
            CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">

    <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding diasCalendario}" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

        <!--Built in Cells-->
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding nomeRotaOnibus}" TextColor="Green" />
                <!--<Label Text="{Binding nomeRotaOnibus}" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" />-->
            </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
  </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

**Código da ListView**

```
public partial class CalendarioOnibus : ContentPage
{

    public const string DiasUteis = "Dias Úteis";
    public const string Sabados = "Sábados";
    public const string DomingosFeriado = "Domingos / Feriados";

    public ObservableCollection<rotaOnibuslist> Items { get; set; }                
    public rotaOnibuslist listaHorario = new rotaOnibuslist(); //inicio aqui para poder usar nos métodos que preciso        

    public CalendarioOnibus(int idBairro, string sentido)
    {            
        InitializeComponent();    

        Task.Run(async () => await carregaHorariosVariantes(idBairro, sentido));
    }

    async Task carregaHorariosVariantes(int idBairro, string sentido)
    {
        //web serice            
        serviceLinha service = new serviceLinha();

        listaViagem viagemOnibus = await service.buscaVariantes(); //variantes e rotas  
        PartidaPrincipal partidaOnibus = await service.buscaHorario(); //horário e calendario (dias)                        

        viagemOnibus.viagens.RemoveAll(x => !x.id_linha.Equals(idBairro));//só deixo o bairro filtrado
        viagemOnibus.viagens.RemoveAll(x => !x.sentido.Equals(sentido));//só deixo o sentido filtrado
        viagemOnibus.viagens.OrderBy(x => x.id_viagem); //ordeno pela viagem que já deixo ordenado para mostrar no lsit view           

        partidaOnibus.partidas.OrderBy(x => x.id_viagem); //orderno pela viagem 

        List<rotaOnibuslist> listaOnibusHorario = new List<rotaOnibuslist>();
        //rotaOnibuslist listaOnibusHorario = new rotaOnibuslist();
        rotaOnibuslist listaHorarioDiasUteis = new rotaOnibuslist();
        rotaOnibuslist listaHorarioSabados = new rotaOnibuslist();
        rotaOnibuslist listaHorarioDomingos = new rotaOnibuslist();

        foreach (Viagem viagem in viagemOnibus.viagens)
        {
            //pego o código da viagem e o nome da mesma
            int codigoViagem = viagem.id_viagem;
            string nomeViagem = viagem.nome;

            foreach (Partida partida in partidaOnibus.partidas)
            {
                if (partida.id_viagem == codigoViagem) {

                    foreach (Calendario diasOnibus in partida.calendarios) {
                        //string dias = diasOnibus.calendario;
                        foreach (listaPartida partidaHorario in diasOnibus.partidas) {
                            string horario = partidaHorario.partida;
                            rotaOnibus onibus = new rotaOnibus() { horarioOnibus = horario, rota = nomeViagem };                                
                            string dias = diasOnibus.calendario;

                            switch (dias)
                            {
                                case DiasUteis:
                                    listaHorarioDiasUteis.diasCalendario = dias;
                                    listaHorarioDiasUteis.Add(onibus);
                                    break;
                                case Sabados:
                                    listaHorarioSabados.diasCalendario = dias;
                                    listaHorarioSabados.Add(onibus);
                                    break;
                                case DomingosFeriado:
                                    listaHorarioDomingos.diasCalendario = dias;
                                    listaHorarioDomingos.Add(onibus);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }            

        listaOnibusHorario.Add(listaHorarioDiasUteis);
        listaOnibusHorario.Add(listaHorarioSabados);
        listaOnibusHorario.Add(listaHorarioDomingos);

        Items = new ObservableCollection<rotaOnibuslist>(listaOnibusHorario);            
        MyListView.ItemsSource = Items;                        
    }
```

**Minhas classes:**

```
public class Calendario
{
    public string calendario { get; set; }
    public listaPartida[] partidas { get; set; }
}

public class listaPartida
{
    public string idTabela { get; set; }
    public string chegada { get; set; }
    public string partida { get; set; }
}


public class Partida
{
    public Calendario[] calendarios { get; set; }
    public int id_viagem { get; set; }
}

public class PartidaPrincipal
{
    public Partida[] partidas { get; set; }
}

public class Viagem
{
    public object nome_curto { get; set; }
    public string sentido { get; set; }
    public string linha { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public int id_linha { get; set; }
    public int id_viagem { get; set; }
}

public class listaViagem
{
    public List<Viagem> viagens { get; set; }
}
```

**Minhas classes na qual faço binding:**

```
public class rotaOnibus
{
    public string horarioOnibus { get; set; }
    public string rota { get; set; }
    public string nomeRotaOnibus
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{horarioOnibus} - {rota}";
        }
    }
}

public class rotaOnibuslist : List<rotaOnibus>
{
    public string diasCalendario { get; set; }
    public List<rotaOnibus> rotaOnibus => this;
}
```

Comment: Recomendaria você reduzir um pouco a quantidade de informações na sua pergunta, destacando mais claramente o ponto onde encontra o problema.

Comment: Ajustado a pergunta para ficar mais clara a dúvida/problema que estou tendo. 
Desde já, agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Problema resolvido.

Irei postar abaixo para caso alguem tenha o mesmo problema:

Na minha list view eu adicionei a propriedade:

```
IsGroupingEnabled="True"
```

Ficando assim:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped"
CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
IsGroupingEnabled="True">
```

No fonte, alterei de:

```
listaOnibusHorario.Add(listaHorarioDiasUteis);
listaOnibusHorario.Add(listaHorarioSabados);
listaOnibusHorario.Add(listaHorarioDomingos);
Items = new ObservableCollection<rotaOnibuslist>(listaOnibusHorario);            
MyListView.ItemsSource = Items;
```

Para:

```
var list = new List<rotaOnibuslist>()
{
    listaHorarioDiasUteis,
    listaHorarioSabados,
    listaHorarioDomingos
};
MyListView.ItemsSource = list;
```

E tambem, no método, adicionei o: base.OnAppearing();

```
public CalendarioOnibus(int idBairro, string sentido)
{            
    InitializeComponent();

    base.OnAppearing();

    Task.Run(async () => await carregaHorariosVariantes(idBairro, sentido));
}
```

E ai apareceu a lista certinho, como devia.